# Bad search result due to strange linked domains

Tags: seo, backlinks, link-building

I have a website which is not scoring good in Google's search results. I use Majestic SEO and Open Site Explorer in order to have a view about my link profile. I now see different backlink domains, some of them already removed, that contains sexual content or other non relative content linking to my domain.

How much influence does these strange linked domains have on my search result?
Even if some of them are already removed for a couple of months. I have already disavow open sexual domains using the tool that Google provides.

Comment: Don't forget to approve the answer, if you are happy with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those websites are spammy and link from and to other low quality websites, then they are in what is called a bad neighborhood. If you link to them or they link to you, then you become part of the bad neighborhood too. It is bad for your rankings.

However, since you most probably do not link to them and you removed (disavowed I guess) those links, then you should not worry about these. Your ranking issues do not come from them. Just make sure to remove bad links if new ones appear.

Comment: And what about business directories? I see 80% of the domains are business directories. What should I do about these?

Comment: If there is editorial content and they are not accepting 'anything', then they are ok. Otherwise, get rid of them, especially if you did not subscribe to them.

Comment: What do you mean with: `If there is editorial content and they are not accepting 'anything', then they are ok.`

Comment: Someone is reviewing what is being submitted to these directories (i.e., it is not automatically accepted).

Comment: What do you think about the following domains: `spidir.com`, `cybo.com`, `europages.dk`

Comment: All crap except europages.dk, but you should do your own research. Check their domain authority and backlink profile.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I had doubts about these because the most links come from those domains, that's why I asked.

Comment: The problem is once your URL is registered in one of these low quality directories, it is automatically propagated to other low quality directories. It is like an infection, get rid of all of them...

Comment: That is another question. You should create another question.

Comment: Google (at least) is better able to determine if spam sites are using content of or linking to non-spam sites over the past few years. It can determine intent fairly well. As well, Google is tracking, registrations, hosting domains (of all types) and knows where the bad domains live and how they move around the Internet. These sites are often discounted quickly when found as not to penalize innocent sites though the process is not prefect by any stretch. The effect has less impact these days, but is something to keep an eye on and fix where possible still.